# How to solve Students marks dashboard kinds of problems - Can't we use simple code in python to solve this problem..?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the marks list of class students given in two lists

```
Students = ['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10']
Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 45, 98, 35, 80]
```

from the above two lists the Student[0] got Marks[0], Student[1] got Marks[1] and so on
Who got marks between >25th percentile <75th percentile, in the increasing order of marks

My question - 
Can't we use simple code in python to solve this problem..?

I have written code till this. To find the numbers >25 and <75 but unable to make it in ascending order. Sort() is not working and sorted is also not working. Please help how to extract the particular array values and assign to another array to solve this problem.

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if Marks[i]>25 and Marks[i]<75: 
        print(Students[i],Marks[i])
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small addition to your code can solve this issue, below is the solution

```
Students = ['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10']
Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 45, 98, 35, 80]

Students,Marks=zip(*sorted(zip(Students, Marks))) #addition to your code

for i in range(0,10):
    if Marks[i]>25 and Marks[i]<75: 
        print(Students[i],Marks[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

25th percentile is "bottom fourth out of those who took the thing", and 75th percentile is "top fourth", regardless of the actual score. So what you need to do is sort the list, then take a slice out of the middle, based on the index.

Here's what I think you're trying to do:

```
import math

students = ['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10']
marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 45, 98, 35, 80]

# zip() will bind together corresponding elements of students and marks
# e.g. [('student1', 45), ('student2', 78), ...]
grades = list(zip(students, marks))

# once that's all in one list of 2-tuples, sort it by calling .sort() or using sorted()
# give it a "key", which specifies what criteria it should sort on
# in this case, it should sort on the mark, so the second element (index 1) of the tuple
grades.sort(key=lambda e:e[1])
# [('student3', 12), ('student4', 14), ('student9', 35), ('student6', 43), ('student1', 45), ('student7', 45), ('student5', 48), ('student2', 78), ('student10', 80), ('student8', 98)]

# now, just slice out the 25th and 75th percentile based on the length of that list
twentyfifth = math.ceil(len(grades) / 4)
seventyfifth = math.floor(3 * len(grades) / 4)
middle = grades[twentyfifth : seventyfifth]

print(middle)
# [('student6', 43), ('student1', 45), ('student7', 45), ('student5', 48)]
```

You have 10 students here, so how you round `twentyfifth` and `seventyfifth` is up to you (I chose to include those strictly those within 25-75th percentile, by rounding 'inwards' - you could do the opposite by switching `ceil` and `floor`, and get your final list to have two more elements in this case - or you could round them both the same way).

Comment: Answer seems correct. Choose Math.floor in both cases for the expected Result.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [@Green Cloak Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648811/green-cloak-guy) answer is the correct. But anyway, if what you want is to get the data of students with marks between two ranges I'll do it like this:

```
# Get a dict of students with it's mark, filtered by those with mark between 25 and 75
students_mark = {s: m for s, m in zip(Students, Marks) if m > 25 and m < 75}
# Sort results
res = dict(sorted(students_mark.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
# res: {'student9': 35, 'student6': 43, 'student1': 45, 'student7': 45, 'student5': 48}

# In one line
res = {s: m for s, m in sorted(zip(Students, Marks), key=lambda i: i[1]) if m > 25 and m < 75}
```

As a summary: first link each student with it's score, and then filter and sort. I stored the result as dictionary because it seems more convinient.